# Strapi custom admin not working on remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, strapi

**I modified the page ./admin/src/containers/HomePage/Index.js** following Strapi documentation https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/custom-admin.html#introduction.

**All works well locally**, I also did a build locally, but I am not able to see this modified page after deploying to Heroku.

I tried to desactivate node_modules caching (like this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior), and I also pushed the file I modified on the repository via a custom **.gitignore** config like this to avoid cache troubles:

```
*.cache/*
!.cache/admin/
*.cache/admin/*
!.cache/admin/src
*.cache/admin/src/*
!.cache/admin/src/containers
*.cache/admin/src/containers/*
!.cache/admin/src/containers/HomePage
*.cache/admin/src/containers/HomePage/*
!.cache/admin/src/containers/HomePage/Index.js
```

*This config only push the file Index.js but not the rest.* But it also doesn't work.

I also installed this cache manager **plugin** (https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache) but  the purge command and redeploying does'nt solve the problem...

**Do you have any idea about how to see my modified admin on Heroku ?**

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found out the solution** witch was stupid. It was because of **a typo**: my filename was **Index.js** instead of **index.js**.

Now my index.js file correctly replace the index.js located in node_modules so everything works fine now.